# \nameref inside custom command

Tags: cross-referencing, arguments

I have created my own command with \newcommand and it Works fine with "static" input in the arguments. But, when I give e.g. a `\nameref{sec:title}` it is throwing errors like these:

- Undefined control sequence
- Missing endcsname inserted
- Extra endcsname

**How can I create a command, that supports this?**

I defined the new command like this:

```
\newcommand{\faqFarm}[6]{
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \label{faqFarm#1}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXX@{}}
             #1 & #2 & #4 & #6 \\
             & #3 & #5 & 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
}
```

**Working example of the error:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\faqFarm}[6]{
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \label{faqFarm#1}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXX@{}}
            \textbf{Navn:} & \textbf{Adresse:} & \textbf{Koordinater:} & \textbf{Jord:}\\
             #1 & #2 & #4 & #6 hektar\\
             & #3 & #5 & 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
    \subsection{Working with nameref in custom command}
    \label{sec:mySubSection}

    the title one more time: \nameref{sec:mySubSection}

    \faqFarm{\nameref{sec:mySubSection}}{Bjerndrupvej 41}{6240 Løgumkloster}{Nord: 55.099754}{Øst: 9.012645}{77,625}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not see any `\nameref` in the code snippet. Also, please, post the *full* error message (e.g. from the `.log` file), because TeX does tell the name of the undefined control sequence in the error message.

Comment: Please make a full compilable example that shows the intended usage of the macro and also exhibiting the issue.

Comment: @egreg I have added a full working minimum example to the question now :)

Comment: As David says, `\label{faqFarm\nameref{sec:mySubSection}}` doesn't make much sense (and breaks); but, without a caption, what's the label for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\faqFarm}[6]
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \label{faqFarm#1}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXX@{}}
             #1 & #2 & #4 & #6 \\
             & #3 & #5 & 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
}
```

You are missing `{` after `[6]`

`\label` should always come after (or in) `\caption` so will not work here

`[h!]` is a bad choice of option and will usually generate a warning that it has been changed. Better to use `[htp]` (it make no sense to routinely use `!`, that is just for special cases where the document constraints need to be ignored)

---

As noted above the `\label` has to come after `\caption` if you need to reference anything other than the page number, but if you want to do this `\label{faqFarm#1}` You need a new (7th) argument that forms the label text, you can not put a reference in a `\label` references involve tests and typesetting commands, and a label has to be an internal identifier of simple ascii characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\faqFarm}[7]{
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \label{faqFarm#7}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXX@{}}
            \textbf{Navn:} & \textbf{Adresse:} & \textbf{Koordinater:} & \textbf{Jord:}\\
             #1 & #2 & #4 & #6 hektar\\
             & #3 & #5 & 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
    \subsection{Working with nameref in custom command}
    \label{sec:mySubSection}

    the title one more time: \nameref{sec:mySubSection}

    \faqFarm{Bjerndrupvej 41}{6240 Løgumkloster}{Nord: 55.099754}{Øst: 9.012645}{77,625}{???}{sec:mySubSection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a copy pase error. I will prepare a fully working example right now, because it still isn't working.

Comment: A working example can be found here on ShareLatex.com: https://da.sharelatex.com/project/55f2ea97added9765e2e0c1d

Comment: @FireFly3000 Please fix the example on this site not external links otherwise the archival use of this site is lost.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have added the minimum code to the question now.

Comment: @FireFly3000 answer extended to cover the case shown